# Is possible to add a google extension from Chrome web store using C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome

Well, in google chrome you can add a lot of extensions where you can find in [Chrome web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions).

I was wondering if is possible to add some extensions programmically using C#.

For example, get the [Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.8) of chrome and with using some 3party or library add specific extension.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions

For Windows you can use registry key

For Linux/MAC use a preference file